# Passing value of Entry in button function

Tags: python, tkinter

How to pass value of `Entry` in button function ?

I want to pass value to a function `onConfirm()`

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Frame, Button, Label, Entry, Text, Checkbutton, \
    Scale, Listbox, Menu, BOTH, RIGHT, RAISED, N, E, S, W, \
    HORIZONTAL, END, FALSE, IntVar, StringVar, messagebox as box

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent, background="skyblue")
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("Simple Window")
        self.style = ttk.Style()
        self.style.theme_use("default")
        self.centreWindow()
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)



        firstNameLabel = Label(self, text="First Name")
        firstNameLabel.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=(100,10), pady=(100,10))

        firstNameText = Entry(self, width=20)
        firstNameText.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(100,10))


        okBtn = Button(self, text="OK", width=10, command= lambda: self.onConfirm(firstNameText.get()))
        okBtn.grid(row=0, column=2,padx = 5, pady=(100,10))

       # closeBtn = Button(self, text="Close", width=10, command=self.onExit)
        #closeBtn.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=3, sticky=W+E)

    def centreWindow(self):
        w = 500
        h = 300
        sw = self.parent.winfo_screenwidth()
        sh = self.parent.winfo_screenheight()
        x = (sw - w)/2
        y = (sh - h)/2
        self.parent.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))



   def onConfirm(self,s):
        box.showinfo("Information", s)

def main():
    root = Tk()

    #root.geometry("250x150+300+300")    # width x height + x + y
    # we will use centreWindow instead
    root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
    # .. not resizable
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code.

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title.

Comment: in class you can use `self` - `self.firstNameText` and get value directly in method `onConfirm` - `self.firstNameText.get()`. You don't have to set it as parameter.

Comment: your code works for me without problems.

Comment: The way youdo with lambda is enoguh to pass the content of the Entry to the desired funcition. Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: your code works for me, after I fixed the indentation error with`onConfirm`.

Comment: @furas I think you've made an indentation mistake when editing the code's formatting.

Comment: @Nae do you mean `onConfirm` ? I only selected all code and used `{}` - and it looked OK. I didn't move every line separately. Currently I don't know if this indention is not main problem in question - so I don't know if I should change this indention.

Comment: @furas Yes, in its initial state it didn't look like it had any space before it.

Comment: @BryanOakley - thank you with correct indentation its working .. i am new to python

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to pass the variable because you are using a class.  Try instead

```
## instance object can be used throughout the class
self.firstNameText = Entry(self, width=20)
self.firstNameText.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=(100,10))

## Button just calls function
okBtn = Button(self, text="OK", width=10, command=self.onConfirm)
okBtn.grid(row=0, column=2,padx = 5, pady=(100,10))

## function has access to instance variable
def onConfirm(self):
    s=self.firstNameText.get()
    box.showinfo("Information", s)
```